# Is there a way to hide all curators from Steam?

Tags: steam

I don't use nor care about the curator function and I constantly have to scroll past the section every time I load up Steam.

Is there a way to permanently hide the all Curators from Steam and never make that section show up again?

Bonus points if you include a way to hide them on the website and not just the Steam client.

Comment: Do you want to still access the store page on startup?

Comment: @JMac Personally, I don't care what I have to do to get the curators to hide. But I'd like to never see them if I ever went to the homepage.

Comment: So the answer posted is sort of a light version of what you're really looking for?  (i.e. you don't have to see curators on startup, but when going to the store page it's still in that same spot)

Comment: @JMac Technically it answers the question and is a valid way to never see them. I'm not opposed to accepting that answer at the moment since I mostly just click on "library" anyway. I'm just curious if there is a legit way to hide that feature all-together.

Comment: This question got me very curious if there's a way as well, that's why I'm digging trying to see where you're coming from.  I don't care too much; but if there is a way to remove the feature I would like to know about it, since I already ignore the curation as is.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot? I am curious where they are, because I don't use curators too and they don't bother me so far. P.S.: I am very sensitive to such *garbage* person, e.g. ads makes me quit all social networks so far.

Comment: @Sinatr I added an answer based on an update today that shows them hidden.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So it turns out if you ignore enough Curators, Steam will automatically start hiding this section. I ignored about 20 Curators and then when I logged in this morning I saw this updated section.

[image: Curators]

Answer (score 0):

Every time I open my Steam I see Activity page - where it says what achievements my friends got or which games they bought. I'm not subscribed to any curators so I don't see them.

My guess is your default page is still Steam Store. You should be able to switch it to something else, I don't have Steam available right now (will test once I'll get home), but [some folks online say](https://steamcommunity.com/discussions/forum/10/666828126452033873/) it's **Settings -> Interface -> Favourite Window**.

Comment: Presumably OP is talking about removing the curators from the Steam Store page, not changing what their opening page shows (if they aren't using the store page, they would have no reason to scroll past the curators that I can think of).